# Neutral pose for animation

Tags: animation, transforms, rigging

In Softimage we have Netrual Pose, it simple set position/rotation/scale to 0 without moving pivot or object self. It just offset your object. I see that in Blender is Delta Transform, so I copy Transform values to Delta transform and set Transform to 0 0 0.

It works as I need, but:

1) Is there better workflow for copy values? Shortcuts, script ...

2) If I Clear Value, it also Clear my Delta, but I need only Transform.

It looks that I will need some scripts for this workflow, but maybe there is better ....

Comment: Do you mean the Rest Position for Pose Mode?

Comment: No, you can imagine some text where every letter will be animated, so my workflow in Softimage was: Create Empty (null object) for every letter, parent and set Empty to neutral pose, so it has all transform 0 0 0, but it is not in same place, because there is offset. It is good if you want set your text to default pose. So I wonder, what workflow is recommended for Blender.

Comment: Are you talking about parenting?

Comment: Yes letters are parented under Emptys, but question is: Is there any option for Empty or another control object for setting to zero transform = neutral pose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first store the expected neutral pose to pose library for further use.

1. Go to **Object Data** tab,  Click [image] button in **Pose Library**;
2. Click [image] on the right-hand side to add/store pose based on current pose;
3. Adjust the armature to the expected neutual pose;
4. Click [image] again to store it.

Then you can apply either one of them back to the armature object by clicking [image] on the right-hand side.

[image]

You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> > **Apply Pose as Rest Pose**, if you want to apply the neutral pose to rest pose (the real zero transformation, not offset) by then.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Leon. It looks that I have to use bones more often than only for character animation. So I have to make armature rig for text too (animated logos). In Softimage you dont need use armature until you need IK and you have all options. NLA, rest pose ... etc. It is different for me :)

Comment: @Cenda Actually, a single bone can be considered as an empty, There's no much difference I bet, right? :)  You can even change it to empty-like appearance.